# How can I make a UICollectionView have natural UIScrollView behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that's set up as image thumbnails, vertical scroll. it seems the `UICollectionView`'s default behavior is to have a page-centric scrolling where it sort of jumps page to page with some inertia.

I've read a number of posts on how to make the cells align in a natural way to the top and bottom, which would possibly work, but not be ideal.

How can you make this behave like a normal `UIScrollView` scroll and just scroll the collection view downward without this page-specific component?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the collection view setup code? They act exactly like scroll views by default — no snapping to anywhere. I'm wondering whether a `pagingEnabled` set has snuck in somewhere.

Comment: Looks like that was it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you rasterising your cells' layers? If not, add these two lines when dequeuing your cells

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Comment: It seems like this answer assumes that the issue is a performance issue, which it isn't. It's about changing the default physics of a paginated UICollectionView to work more like a standard scrollview. For instance, if you slightly pull up the collection view from the bottom, the physics will pull it back down towards the bottom of the page. This isn't default UIScrollView behavior.